# boost::asio data owning `ConstBufferSequence`

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, object-lifetime, asio

The last days, I read alot through the asio examples and other questions here on SO regarding lifetime management of buffers passed to asios initiating functions. One issue that strikes me, is that there seems to be no "by value" solution, but instead the caller of the initiating function always needs to ensure that the buffers are valid until the async operation completes. Often this is achieved by creating shared pointers to the data and copying them into the handlers.

In my case I am already using the `async_write` overload where a `ConstBufferSequence` is passed in which holds e.g. the sizeof the next message followed by the next message. I.e.

```
auto message = std::make_shared<std::string>("hello");
auto size = std::make_shared<std::uint32_t>(message.size());
std::vector<asio::const_buffer> buffers = {asio::buffer(size, sizeof(*size)), asio::buffer(*message)};
asio::async_write(_socket, buffers, [message,size](...){...}); // prolong lifetime by coping shared ptrs.
```

So I was thinking about writing a custom `Message` class that fulfills the `ConstBufferSequence` concept but also **owns** the underlying message. I dug a little into the code, and found, that at one place the buffer sequence argument, which is at first passed into `asio::async_write` via `const&` gets passed along via `const&` until it finally is copied into a member variable of the `asio::detail::write_op` class.

So here the actual question(s):

- Can this approach work for a fire and forget call? This would translate above intos  something like:
  `asio::async_write(_socket, Message("hello"),[](auto,auto){});`
- Are there any issues with the lifetime of the constbuffer sequence arguments w.r.t. composed operations?
- Would this be a good idea? It obviously goes against the "normal" asio way of dealing with buffer lifetime management.

Curious about your thoughts - Criticism welcome! ;-)

Regards, Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a `shared_buffer` before (I think it was in the Asio docs/exmples, will search later).

Furthermore there's obviously

- boost::asio::streambuf
- the Beast buffer models (flat_buffer, multi_buffer, vector_buffer)

Of course, it just moves the problem from an ownership issue into a life-time issue.

The upside of having Boost Asio's buffer concept being "ref-only" or "view-semantics" is that

- you never run into life-time issues passing those references around by value , and
- they lend themselves *very well* to implementing composed operations the right way: without assumptions about the buffer organization

---

Found the Asio example:  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/buffers/reference_counted.cpp these days lives in

- example/cpp03/buffers/reference_counted.cpp
- example/cpp11/buffers/reference_counted.cpp

### Addressing the bullets

> Can this approach work for a fire and forget call? This would translate above intos something like: asio::async_write(_socket, Message("hello"),{});

Yes

> Are there any issues with the lifetime of the constbuffer sequence arguments w.r.t. composed operations?

Not if you manage it well, which is a requirement anyways

> Would this be a good idea? It obviously goes against the "normal" asio way of dealing with buffer lifetime management.

Depends on how you do it. If you end up copying the buffer wholesale it would be costly, and also wouldn't work with some async operations (which require the buffer to have *reference stability*, meaning: not change address, in other words, not move around).

Granted with move-semantics many buffer types might still be able to offer this property, but the problem with buffers being passed by-value is that they might make multiple copies, which

- either doesn't compile (because they're not rvalues)
- or (if you hack it with a moving copy constructor/assignment) might lead to UB when a moved-from copy is used

Comment: Added the `shared_const_buffer` example and addressed the individual question bullets

Comment: I think going through the boost beast docs about the available `DynamicBuffer` implementations gave me the rest :D - I think what I planned was similar to beasts Dynamic buffer implementations, but I will not go that route. I came to the conculsion, that it just obfuscates whats going on in my context. And the "fire and forget" approach really only helps when sending (not receiving) so I guess its not worth coming up with a propper own implementation... Thanks for pointing me the right way :)

Comment: @MartiNito Cheers. I agree with your assessment. For "fire and forgt" I find that often it's very convenient to have a `std::list<std::string>` or similar because that also aids in queuing outgoing messages in a full-duplex scenario. `std::list` has reference stability so that's perfect.